# Problem of using Tikz in beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, matrices, tikz-matrix

I used Tikz to draw some specific shapes on a matrix, this the MWE that I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=4pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-4pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,row sep=0em,column sep=0em,nodes={inner sep=6pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,text width=0.6em,align=center] (m)  
    {
    a & b & c \\ 
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    };
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.5mm}
    \draw [thick,blue,rounded corners=1mm] (m-1-1.west) |- (m-3-3.south) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick,red,rounded corners=1mm] (m-1-1.north) -| (m-3-3.east) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick,green,rounded corners=1mm] ([yshift=\offset]m-1-1.west) -- ([xshift=-\offset]m-1-1.north) -- ([yshift=-\offset]m-3-3.east) -- ([xshift=\offset]m-3-3.south) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

but when I tried this code in a beamer presentation (theme: Warsaw) I get this: 
[image]

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example of the beamer use (that makes it much faster for others to test and suggest solutions)

Comment: Tested with `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}` and works fine on share latex... may be you need a second run if didn't tried

Comment: I think it would be appropriate if you mentioned that you got that nice code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445672/121799).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a `fragile` frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrixenv/.style={decoration=brace,every left delimiter/.style={xshift=4pt},every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-4pt}}}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=[,right delimiter={]},inner sep=1pt,row sep=0em,column sep=0em,nodes={inner sep=6pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm,mymatrixenv]
    \matrix [mymatrix,text width=0.6em,align=center] (m)  
    {
    a & b & c \\ 
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    };
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.5mm}
    \draw [thick,blue,rounded corners=1mm] (m-1-1.west) |- (m-3-3.south) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick,red,rounded corners=1mm] (m-1-1.north) -| (m-3-3.east) -- cycle;
    \draw [thick,green,rounded corners=1mm] ([yshift=\offset]m-1-1.west) -- ([xshift=-\offset]m-1-1.north) -- ([yshift=-\offset]m-3-3.east) -- ([xshift=\offset]m-3-3.south) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a slight idea what difference the option *fragile* makes (internally)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Only a very rough idea. It more or less treats the content of the frame as verbatim material and limits the amount of processing which is normally done. For tikz the most noticeable effect is that tikz can still use one `#`. Without the fragile option one would need `###`.

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Wouldn't it be a a good idea then, to set fragile as the standard frame option? Apart from a maybe slower compilation process. Or is this rather a own question?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No. Having fragile as standard option causes quite some problems. It should only be used if necessary.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner To give a few examples: it interact badly with other options like `shrink` or `allowframebreaks`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply. I prepare an introduction for LaTeX beginners and therefore wondered if that could be a good idea :)